# Align numbers using only sed

Tags: bash, sed

I need to align decimal numbers with the "," symbol using only the sed command. The "," should go in the 5th position. For example:

```
183,7 

    2346,7 

        7,999
```

Should turn into:

```
  183,7 

 2346,7 

    7,999
```

The maximum amount of numbers before the comma is 4. I have tried using this to remove spaces:

```
sed 's/ //g' input.txt > nospaces.txt
```

And then I thought about adding spaces depending on the number of digits before the comma, but I don't know how to do this using only sed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why only `sed`? Sed is not the tool I'd choose for this.

Comment: I have been asked to do it only using sed

Comment: By your teacher or by a co-worker?

Comment: This might help: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Centering-lines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is only one number on each line; that there are at most four digits before the `,`, and that there is always a `,`:

```
sed 's/[^0-9,]*\([0-9]\+,[0-9]*\).*/    \1/;s/.*\(.....,.*\)/\1/;'
```

The first `s` gets rid of everything other than the (first) number on the line, and puts four spaces before it. The second one deletes everything before the fifth character prior to the `,`, leaving just enough spaces to right justify the number.

The second `s` command might mangle input lines which didn't match the first `s` command. If it is possible that the input contains such lines, you can add a conditional branch to avoid executing the second substitution if the first one failed. With Gnu sed, this is trivial:

```
sed 's/[^0-9,]*\([0-9]\+,[0-9]*\).*/    \1/;T;s/.*\(.....,.*\)/\1/;'
```

`T` jumps to the end of the commands if the previous `s` failed. Posix standard sed only has a conditional branch on success, so you need to use this circuitous construction:

```
sed 's/[^0-9,]*\([0-9]\+,[0-9]*\).*/    \1/;ta;b;:a;s/.*\(.....,.*\)/\1/;'
```

where `ta` (conditional branch to `a` on success) is used to skip over a `b` (unconditional branch to end). `:a` is the label referred to by the `t` command.

Answer (score 0):

if you change your mind, here is an `awk` solution

```
$ awk -F, 'NF{printf "%5d,%-d\n", $1,$2} !NF' file

  183,7

 2346,7

    7,999
```

set the delimiter to comma and handle both parts as separate fields

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
gawk -F, '{ if($0=="") print ; else printf "%5d,%-d\n", $1, $2 }' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **GNU sed**, you could do as below

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]+),([0-9]+)/printf "%5s,%d" \1 \2/e' input.txt
```